# Stringifying query parameters: can we go further?

Tags: ruby

I wrote this method:

```rb
    def stringify_query_params(query_parameters)
      stringified_query_params = ''
      query_parameters.each_with_index do |kv, i|
        k, v = kv
        index = i
        if index == 0
          stringified_query_params += "?#{k}=#{v}"
        else
          stringified_query_params += "&#{k}=#{v}"
        end
      end
      return stringified_query_params
    end
```

RubyCop is complaining in my running instance of RubyMine saying that I should instead be capturing the output of the conditional branching logic like this.

I was able to make it slightly better, using some methods in the Enumerable module

```rb
   def stringify_query_parameters(query_parameters)
      query_parameters.each_with_object([]).with_index do |((k, v), acc), index|
        acc.push((index.positive? ? '&' : '?') + "#{k}=#{v}")
      end.join('')
    end
```

Can anyone think of a way to make it even terser?

Comment: Keep in mind that you also need to escape both keys and values. If this just an exercise, carry on. If you want to use this in production, you are better of using `URI.encode_www_form`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be as follows:

```
def stringify_query_parameters(query_parameters)
  '?' + query_parameters.map{ |k, v| "#{k}=#{v}" }.join('&')
end
```